# Printing two hollow mirrored triangles recursively in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i,j,n;
 char ch;

printf("Enter number of rows: ");
scanf("%d%c",&n,&ch);
printf("Enter the symbol: ");
ch=getchar();

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{

    for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
    {
      printf(" ");
    }

    if(i==1 || i==n)
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",ch);
        }
    else
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {  
            if(j==1 || j==i)
                printf("%c",ch);
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");               
}             

return 0;
}
```

This code basically prints a triangle made by x's using a For loop. How can I convert this code into a function implementing Recursion? And how can I print a large X composed of smaller X's with a given “width”, n,
which is guaranteed to be odd. Example an X of width n = 7.

Comment: Move everything except the part that asks for the number of rows and the symbol into a function, and make those variables parameters of the function.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understaning:  1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: char ch;` and `ch=getchar();`  the function `getchar()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: OT: please do not skip braces '{' '}' around the body of a `for()`, `while()` loops and `if()` statements

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d%c",&n,&ch);` always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful  (in this case any returned value other than 2 indicates an error

Comment: exactly what is the posted code expecting the input to look like?  Exactly what is the posted code expected to output?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: It there any particular reason this statement: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` was not written as: `for(i=0;i<n;i++)?`  A similar question exists for the statement: `for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++)`